# Busy indicator for Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It is possible to implement busy indicator to indicate the processing of the controller for form postback call without using AJAX?

Comment: Have a look at this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633201/mvc-validation-form-submit-cursor-waiting-issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this using html. Add this in common view. Using java-script call the ID where ever you want like this **$("#loading").show()** to show and **$("#loading").hide()** to hide

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <table style="height: 100%; border: 0; width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: #FAFAFA; opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80); z-index: 9000;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%; text-align:center; vertical-align : middle;">                <div id="Loadingtext" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 24px; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); font-weight: bold; color: #000000; text-align: center; padding-top: 5px;">Please wait</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```